# What is this flowering succulent?

Tags: identification, flowers, cactus

I just moved into this house and there are a few random potted plants left over from the previous tenants. I live in Perth, Western Australia.

I recently gave this one some water since it didn't look dead and suddenly it had these shoots growing off of it. Then a couple of days later they bloomed into large white flowers.

[image: plant with flower]
[image: flower close up]
[image: pre-flower shoot]

Comment: "Succulent" means "water storage on stem". But from that photos, stem and leaves are flat.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi , jungle cacti do contain succulent tissue, but to a lesser extent than the desert cacti

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an orchid cactus, Epiphyllum oxypetallum, also known as Night Blooming cactus - can be grown in a trailing fashion if given plenty of sun and little water, as a more upright plant given shade and more water. Not frost tolerant, needs temperatures above 40 deg F. Flowers should be fragrant, and only last one night, more info here http://herselfshouseplants.com/orchid-cactus-epiphyllum-oxypetallum/

Comment: Thanks for the info on caring for this plant. I was very pleasantly surprised by the sudden appearance of the flowers when I thought it was just your average cactus plant. I'll do my best to keep it happy. =)